# Azure Functions local authentication with Azure AD B2C

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to use Azure AD B2C authentication in a localhost Azure Functions project? If yes, how can this be done?

There are examples of using Azure AD B2C authentication for local ASP.NET Core projects, but I have not seen any examples for local functions projects.

Answer (score -4):

As `Azure Function` is designed to run a small spice of code. You can not add AAD authentication to it as you do to an ASP.NET project directly.

Some ideas:

1. For cloud environment, you can integrate AAD authentication from Azure portal. Here is a tutorial: [ADDING AZURE AD B2C AUTHENTICATION TO AZURE FUNCTIONS](https://codemilltech.com/adding-azure-ad-b2c-authentication-to-azure-functions/)
2. You can always manually get the authentication header from a http request. And then manually verify the token you get to see if it is authenticated.

Comment: This example uses AD B2C to add authentication to a local ASP.NET Core Web API. Can the same be done for a functions project?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=applications#configure-the-sample